# Indexes not being used

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014

I just moved my large database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 and have experience problems with indexes not being used.

The problem only occurs when I have a `SELECT` within a `SELECT` using `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblChildren 
WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ParentID 
                   FROM tblParents 
                   WHERE Office = 1)
```

The index is on `tblChildren`, column `ParentID`.

The following statements trigger the index just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblChildren 
WHERE ParentID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblChildren 
WHERE ParentID = 1
```

I do not want to change any of the code or SQL statements to force the index to be used, I just need it to do it automatically like it use to. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Might be a different plan due to the new cardinality estimator. What compatibility level is the database in? What are the table definitions including indexes? How many rows in both tables? How many returned by `SELECT ParentID FROM tblParents WHERE Office=1`? How many returned by the whole query?

Comment: The inner select returns on average 5-10 records. The children contains 20 million records and parents about 4 million. So it hit the CPU like crazy, hence why I noticed it. The database in 2008 compatibility.

Comment: Has the database collation remained the same? As you aren't using two part names it would be possible for that query to change semantics if `tblChildren` has a column called `ParentID` and `tblParents` has a column called `ParentId` and you switch to a CS collation.

Comment: Nothing has changed at all. I literally just did a backup and restore to the new server with 0 changes.

Comment: Try updating statistics and see if you still get the same plan.

Comment: For some reason the statistics where updated with a small sample size. Doing full scan update statistics resolved the problem. Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the table statistics were lost and a bad plan was cached for the query because of that, which is now being reused. Try updating the statistics with `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.tblParents` and also for the child table. Then use `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear out the query plans. If you can find your query in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` then you can just clear the plan for that specific query, which would be preferred. Check the documentation on `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` for more information on removing a specific query plan.